# How do I remove a validation formula?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I submitted a couple of validation formulas in one of my columns but I would like to restore the column to the original or hopefully removed the validation formula completely. PLEASE HELP!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by removing formula from List Setting => Validation Setting.  Remove the formula from the Formula Box.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry it's not duplicated answer but you were faster than me (15 Sec) :)

Comment: No worries @M.Qassas

Answer (score 0):

- Go to list Settings > General Setting > Validation Setting
- Check your column and its formula, remove and modify it as you like at Formula Textbox
  [image]